# Dictionary not appending to list

Tags: python, python-3.x

*The purpose of this code is to iterate through a list of dictionaries, check in each dictionary if it matches with the name of the item, if it does, increment the value, if not, add the dictionary to the list. I've added a print just to show you whats in the array and what is recognised as the parameter of the function*

Problem:
The dictionary does not get added to the array.

Code:

```
items = []

def addToCart(item):
    global items
    for k in items:
        if k['name'] == item['name']:
            k['quantity'] += item['quantity']
        else:
            items.append(item)
    print(items, item)
addToCart({'name':'apple', 'quantity' : 3})
```

results:

```
[] {'name':'apple', 'quantity' : 3}
```

expected results:

```
[{'name':'apple', 'quantity' : 3}] {'name':'apple', 'quantity' : 3}
```

Comment: Please add the result you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Items is an empty list, so you iterate over it zero times. Thus none of the code in the for loop is executed,